# log4cxx configureandwatch no effect?

Tags: log4cxx, propertyconfigurator

I have a problem with the configure functionnality.
I want to reload my configuration file when I click on a button.

I call the function

```
std::string filepath = "../../configurationfile.txt"
log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configureAndWatch(log4cxx::File(filepath));
```

I try this one too:

```
log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configure(log4cxx::File(filepath));
```

But the file was only reloaded after 60 second.

Do you have any idea about how to forced the reload of the file ?
The first time, i configure with the configureAndWatch function.

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need help with this issue anymore, but I'll go ahead and answer this one anyway.

configureAndWatch() is usually used to spawn a thread that will periodically check the configuration file for changes. The default delay is of 60 seconds, you can modify that value by using this

```
int delay_in_milliseconds = /* Small delay value */
log4cxx::PropertyConfigurator::configure(log4cxx::File(filepath), delay_in_milliseconds);
```

However, I would recommend against such a technique because of unnecessary checks it will spawn. Instead try using a separate function associated with the button that calls upon

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
```

followed by a

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(filepath);
```

The reason being that with the configure() call the existing configuration is not cleared nor reset immediately. Although, I haven't tried this but I believe calling the  resetConfiguration() function should apply the changes at that instant.